# como fazer insert numa chave estrangeira que está dentro de uma chave estrangeira?

Tags: sql

Pretendo fazer insert na coluna salario e nome_funcao da tabela **funcao** que é chave estrangeira na tabela departamento e essa tabela é chave-estrangeira na tabela funcionário...

Mas as duas colunas **salario** e **nome_salario** tem que se fazer insert apartir da tabela funcionario atraves do Id_deprtamento para ir buscar o ID_funcao que está dentro da tabela

Eu fiz assim

```
    CREATE TABLE FUNCIONARIO
(
    ID_FUNCIONARIO INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    NOME_FUNCIONARIO VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    NOME_PAI VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    NOME_MAE VARCHAR(100)NOT NULL,
    N_BI VARCHAR(50)UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    DATA_NASC VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    GENERO VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    ESTA_CIVIL VARCHAR(100)NOT NULL,
    FOTO VARCHAR (100) NOT NULL,
    ID_DEPARTAMENTO INT,
    ID_MUNICIPIO INT,
    DATA_HORA VARCHAR (100)NOT NULL,
    USUARIO VARCHAR (100)NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_FUNC PRIMARY KEY (ID_FUNCIONARIO),

    CONSTRAINT PK_FUNC_MUNI FOREIGN KEY (ID_MUNICIPIO)
    REFERENCES FUNCAO (ID_FUNCAO),

    CONSTRAINT PK_FUNC_DEP FOREIGN KEY (ID_DEPARTAMENTO)
    REFERENCES DEPARTAMENTO (ID_DEPARTAMENTO)
)

CREATE TABLE DEPARTAMENTO
(
    ID_DEPARTAMENTO INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    NOME_DEP VARCHAR(100)NOT NULL,
    ID_FUNCAO INT ,
    CONSTRAINT PK_DEP PRIMARY KEY (ID_DEPARTAMENTO),
    CONSTRAINT PK_DEP_FUNCAO FOREIGN KEY (ID_FUNCAO)
    REFERENCES FUNCAO (ID_FUNCAO)
)
USE PRESENCA1
CREATE TABLE FUNCAO
(
    ID_FUNCAO INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    NOME_FUNCAO VARCHAR(100)NOT NULL,
    SALARIO VARCHAR(100)NOT NULL,
    DATA VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_FUNCAO PRIMARY KEY (ID_FUNCAO)
)
```

Estou a usar este insert
no Visual studio

```
INSERT INTO FUNCIONARIO (NOME_FUNCIONARIO,NOME_PAI,NOME_MAE,N_BI,DATA_NASC,GENERO,ESTA_CIVIL,FOTO,ID_DEPARTAMENTO ,ID_MUNICIPIO,DATA_HORA,USUARIO
```

O campo **Nome_Funcao** e **Salario** da tabela funcao faz-se o **insert** a partir da tabela **funcionário**, mas essas duas tabela são chave estrangeira na tabela **departamento** e a tabela é chave estrangeira na tabela **FUNCIONARIO**

Esses dois campos têm que ser mostrados na tabela funcionário

Comment: Insere a função, depois insere o departamento e depois insere o funcionário. Não é só fazer na ordem certa?

Answer (score -1):

Sou novo por aqui, não posso comentar por causa que não tenho pontos, então vou responder o melhor possível.

Veja que na criação da tabela `FUNCIONARIO` está informando a restrição de que o **`ID_MUNICIPIO`** referencia **`ID_FUNCAO`**

```
CONSTRAINT PK_FUNC_MUNI FOREIGN KEY (ID_MUNICIPIO) REFERENCES FUNCAO (ID_FUNCAO)
```

Isso provavelmente é um erro, pois caso você esteja passando um `ID_MUNICIPIO`, por exemplo `ID_MUNICIPIO = 2125` e se não existir esse valor em `ID_FUNCAO` da tabela `Funcao`, acarretará um erro de violação de chave primária.

Verifique os valores que estão sendo informados no seu `insert` e depois verifique se os valores das chaves estrangeiras existem nas tabelas que estão sendo referenciadas nos comandos de criação de tabelas `REFERENCES`.

Se você realmente quer ter o `ID_Funcao` na tabela `Funcionario`, realize a inclusão deste novo campo, mas não tente reutilizar um campo como o `ID_MUNICIPIO` que já esteja populado com informações que referenciavam outra tabela.

No seu comando `insert` está faltando a palavra **`VALUES`**, corrija:

```
INSERT INTO FUNCIONARIO VALUES ('Geek_Aprendiz','Alan Turing','Ada Lovelace','BI 123','01/01/2001','MASCULINO','SOLTEIRO','FOTO01.JPG',1,2125,'15/04/2021 11:21:32','USUÁRIO 123')
```

Nesse exemplo acima, caso não exista a função com o ID_Funcao = 2125, ocorrerá o erro:

```
The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "PK_FUNC_MUNI". 
The conflict occurred in database "PRESENCA1", table "dbo.FUNCAO", column 'ID_FUNCAO'.
```

Considerando um banco de dados vazio, os comandos a seguir obtiveram sucesso:

```
insert into FUNCAO VALUES('PROGRAMADOR','7.000,00','10/01/2021')
insert into FUNCAO VALUES('DESENVOLVIMENTO DE SOFTWARE','10.000,00','01/01/2000')
insert into DEPARTAMENTO VALUES ('GERÊNCIA DE SOFTWARE WEB',2);
INSERT INTO FUNCIONARIO VALUES ('Geek_Aprendiz','Alan Turing','Ada Lovelace','BI 123','01/01/2001','MASCULINO','SOLTEIRO','FOTO01.JPG',1,2,'15/04/2021 11:21:32','USUÁRIO 123')
```

Para solucionar seus problemas:

1. Corrija, se necessário, `CONSTRAINT PK_FUNC_MUNI FOREIGN KEY (ID_MUNICIPIO) REFERENCES FUNCAO (ID_FUNCAO)`
2. Corrija o seu comando `insert`, está faltando a palavra **`VALUES`**;
3. Verifique os dados que estão sendo enviados no seu `insert`

Por favor, informe se a explicação e solução sugerida resolveu seu problema, sou um aprendiz buscando aprender a cada dia.